# Use "Create React App" inside a WordPress plugin

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, webpack, embed, create-react-app

I'd like to develop a plugin, where the admin frontend (e.g. wp-admin pages) is rendered with React.

I'm using [`create-react-app`](https://create-react-app.dev/) for developing the app in a subfolder.

For loading the React App into the WordPress admin, I'm looking at the `entrypoints` in `build/asset-mainfest.json` and ensure to enqueue them in the right order.

The React App starts nicely, but all relative paths are broken, e.g. following does not work (I know this is a [Webpack feature](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/#loading-images)):

```
import logo from "./logo.jpg";

function App() {
  return <img src={logo} alt="" />;
}

export default App;
```

The reason it's breaking is, that Webpack assumes the `build` folder to be at the root.

I've seen some solutions to this, but none are satisfying for my needs:

1. [Here](https://ghostinspector.com/blog/develop-wordpress-plugin-with-webpack-and-react/) the author just prevents code-splitting, but still suffers from the same issue as above. It just does not consider other assets.
2. [Here](https://medium.com/swlh/wordpress-create-react-app-integration-30b41657b79e) the author is setting `"homepage": "/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/react-app/build"` in `package.json`. But I think this would break, if WordPress was hosted in a subdirectory itself (like `mywebsite.com/blog`)
3. [Here](https://medium.com/@CodeCareerCoach/react-app-inside-a-wordpress-page-or-post-4c7d38181b3d) the `homepage` is set to a specific domain, too, which makes the plugin not distributable.
4. There was another article that suggested adding a HTML `base` attribute to the head. But there may be other relative links that get broken by that.
5. [Setting the homepage to `"."`](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#serving-the-same-build-from-different-paths) won't work either, since I'm not serving the `build` folder itself.

Do you have a good idea for how I should go about importing assets with `create-react-app` here? I want the plugin to work however WordPress was set up.
My best guess is to pass React the URL to an assets folder and write something like `<img src={props.assetsUrl + '/logo.jpg'} />`, just avoiding these imports altogether.
I'd like to avoid using an `iframe`, because this causes other troubles I don't want to deal with... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems I've found someone else, who had the same problem:
https://dev.to/n1ru4l/configure-the-cra-public-url-post-build-with-node-js-and-express-4n8

You can set the `PUBLIC_URL` env var to a placeholder (in `package.json`)
`"build": "cross-env PUBLIC_URL=__PUBLIC_URL_PLACEHOLDER__ react-scripts build && node scripts/patch-public-url.js"`

... and call a script to replace all your placeholders with `window.__PUBLIC_URL__` (see the provided link for `scripts/patch-public-url.js`, there only JavaScript files get processed).

Then you can localize the script with
`wp_localize_script( $handle, '__PUBLIC_URL__', $assets_url );`
where `$assets_url` is the URL to your React `build` folder, determined dynamically.

Done! You may want to choose something else than `__PUBLIC_URL__`, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating .env and .env.local files.

.env file:

REACT_APP_ASSETS=.../wp-content/plugins/...plugin name.../build/assets/

.env.local file:

REACT_APP_ASSETS=assets/

Then used it like this:

```
<img src={process.env.REACT_APP_ASSETS + "logo.png"} />
```